# How can I obtain a document from a Cosmos DB using a field in an array as a filter?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Cosmos DB with documents that look like the following:

```js
{
  "name": {
      "productName": "someProductName"
  },
  "identifiers": [
     {
         "identifierCode": "1234",
         "identifierLabel": "someLabel1"
     },
     {
         "identifierCode": "432",
         "identifierLabel": "someLabel2"
     }
  ]
}
```

I would like to write a sql query to obtain an entire document using "identifierLabel" as a filter when searching for the document.

I attempted to write a query based on an example I found from the following [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/understanding-how-to-query-arrays-in-azure-cosmos-db/):

```sql
SELECT c,t AS identifiers
FROM c
JOIN t in c.identifiers
WHERE t.identifierLabel = "someLabel2"
```

However, when the result is returned, it appends the following to the end of the document:

```js
{
  "name": {
      "productName": "someProductName"
  },
  "identifiers": [
     {
         "identifierCode": "1234",
         "identifierLabel": "someLabel1"
     },
     {
         "identifierCode": "432",
         "identifierLabel": "someLabel2"
     }
  ]
},
{
         "identifierCode": "432",
         "identifierLabel": "someLabel2"
}
```

How can I avoid this and get the result that I desire, i.e. the entire document with nothing appended to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`, you should be able to do something like this to retrieve the entire document, without any need for a self-join:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.identifiers, {"identifierLabel":"someLabel2"}, true)
```

Note that `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` can search for either scalar values or objects. By specifying `true` as the third parameter, it signifies searching through objects. So, in the above query, it's searching all objects in the array where `identifierLabel` is set to `"someLabel2"` (and then it should be returning the original document, unchanged, avoiding the issue you ran into with the self-join).